# Web Push : Should I use different VAPID for different instance of a Web Application ?

Tags: push-notification, web-push, vapid

In case of multiple instances of a web application running, should each instance have their own pair of VAPID keys or it's fine to use only one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same VAPID key pair for multiple websites / domains. Nothing technical prevents you from doing that.

However if the senders are not related, I suggest that you use different VAPID key pairs.